# To find the eigen-vectors for an infinitely differentiable function

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, generalized-eigenvector

Let

$$V = \{f : \Bbb{R} \to  \Bbb{R} | f \text{ infinitely many times differentiable functions} \}$$ be the vector space over $\Bbb{R}$. Find the eigenvectors of the differential operator $d/dt : V \to V$ . I had taken $f = e^{λt}$, and so $e^{λt}$ is the eigen vectors for every λ in  $\Bbb{R}$.  Is this the correct approach? Is there any matrix representation for this operator?

Comment: The problem wants you to find an $f \in V$ such that $\mathrm df / \mathrm dt = \lambda f$. Here the vector space is a set of functions, so eigenvectors are particular functions! If that's enough to get you started I would strongly encourage you *not* to look at any detailed solutions!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  To being with, surround al math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs.